# Conditional width with CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="field">
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
</div>

<div class="field">
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
</div>
```

Is there any way I could set width on input conditionally based on label. So if label exists:

```
.field label {
  width:25%;
}
.field input {
  width:75%;
}
```

else:

```
.field input {
  width:100%;
}
```

I could do it with javascript but wanted to know if its possible with CSS only.

Comment: You can do it with SASS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)(`~`) does exactly what you want. It basically selects the second element only if preceded by the first element.

Try it like this:

```css
.field label {
  width:25%;
}

/* Default style */
.field input {
  width:100%;
}

/* If preceded by a label, input gets different style */
.field label ~ input {
  width:75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <label>Label</label>
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
</div>

<div class="field">
  <input type="text" name="" value="">
</div>
```

**Update:** Just realized that you could also use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors)(`+`) IF the `label` is guaranteed to immediately precede the input. General sibling selectors(`~`) are a part of CSS3 so might not work in incompatible browsers, while adjacent sibling selectors(`+`) are a part of CSS2.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was possible with `~` just haven't used it much so wasn't sure.